# Should I use clean() to fetch Product of provided Product id in Django Form?

Tags: django, django-forms, django-validation

Is it semantically correct in Django to fetch a `Product` object of provided `Product` id in the `clean()` function, or should I do this somewhere else?

**forms.py**

```
def clean_product(self):
    product_id = self.cleaned_data['product']

    try:
        product = Product.objects.get(id=int(product_id))
    except ValueError:
        raise ValidationError('Invalid value')

    return product
```

**views.py**

```
def submit_new(request):
    status = 'fail'

    if request.method == 'POST':
        form = NewBForm(request.POST)

        if form.is_valid():
            ...    
            b = form.save(commit=False)
            boost.save()

            status = 'success'

    return JsonResponse({'status': status})
```

Comment: If I understood it correctly, you don't need `b.product = form.cleaned_data['product']`, because django forms can handle storing ForeignKey data by itself.

Comment: Yeah thanks, you are right about that.

Comment: Please post your form and model definitions. Also note that Django forms have a `ModelChoiceField` for this use case.